# Rails help looping through has one and belongs to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my kategori controller show action:

```
  def show
    @kategori = Kategori.find(params[:id])
    @konkurrancer = @kategori.konkurrancer

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @kategori }
    end
  end
```

This is kategori view show file:

```
<% @konkurrancer.each do |vind| %>
      <td><%= vind.name %></td>
      <td>4 ud af 5</td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(vind.vaerdi, :unit => "DKK", :separator => ".", :delimiter => ".", :format => "%n %u", :precision => 0) %></td>
      <td>2 min</td>
      <td>Nyhedsbrev</td>
      <td><%= vind.udtraekkes.strftime("%d %B") %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

My kategori model:

```
class Kategori < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :konkurrancer
end
```

My konkurrancer model:

```
class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :kategori
end
```

I want show all of the konkurrancer that have an association to the kategori model

With my code I get the following error:
NoMethodError in Kategoris#show

Showing C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/kategoris/show.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `each' for "#":Konkurrancer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to loop over a has_one association. A has_one means exactly that - has **one**, so you can't call each on this because there is only one. You can do one of the following things to solve the problem in your code:

Use a has_many association:

```
class Kategori < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :konkurrancers
end
```

Use a has_one association and modify your view:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= @konkurrancer.name %></td>
  <td>4 ud af 5</td>
  <td><%= number_to_currency(@konkurrancer.vaerdi, :unit => "DKK", :separator => ".", :delimiter => ".", :format => "%n %u", :precision => 0) %></td>
  <td>2 min</td>
  <td>Nyhedsbrev</td>
  <td><%= @konkurrancer.udtraekkes.strftime("%d %B") %></td>
</tr>
```

Which one you use really depends on your data model. If Kategori have many Konkurrancers then use the first example. If Kategori has one Konkurrancer, then use the second example. Both are valid.

Comment: I used has many. I will approve your answer as fast I can (5 minutes to go)